# Casting with Stream API

Tags: java, generics, casting, java-8, java-stream

I'm not sure why this code doesn't compile (case 1)

```
List list = new LinkedList<>();
List<Long> longList = list.stream()
    .map(value -> (Long) ((Map) value).get("id"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but this code compile successfully (case 2)

```
List list = new LinkedList<>();

Stream<Long> longStream = list.stream()
    .map(value -> (Long) ((Map) value).get("id"));

List<Long> longList = longStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and this code compile successfully to (case 3)

```
List<Object> list = new LinkedList<>();
List<Long> longList = list.stream()
    .map(value -> (Long) ((Map) value).get("id"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My colleague suppose that this connected with

> Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or `Object` if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.

from [Java SE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

So in case 1 list is unbounded that's why compiler replace all types with `Object`.

In case 2 we create generic `Stream` of `Long` and this stream can't be unbounded. Compiler do nothing.

In case 3 we have `List` of `Object` and there is no replacing during compilation.

The question is what the real difference between this 3 cases?

Comment: mixing raw types with generics is never a good idea...

Comment: I know but that's not my idea. Hibernate criteria.list() return raw type in some cases and I'm looking for "best" code to map and collect data using stream api.

Answer (score 3):

Your `List list` is a raw type and this has the effect of making all the methods you call on it raw types as well, even though you might later return a generic type. i.e. you map() notional returns a `Stream<Long>` but the compiler only sees it as a non-generic `Stream`

By assigning it to a variable, you are effectively casting it to a generic.

What I suggest you do is

```
List<Map<String, Long>> list = new LinkedList<>();
List<Long> longList = list.stream()
    .map(value -> value.get("id"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. You prove my colleague idea about raw type and type erase.